# Clear an entry boxes in the new window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to clear my entry boxes in the new window, but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me to solve this problem? Here is my code below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def new_deal():

    def add_new_deal():
        for each_entry in entry:
            each_entry.delete(0, END)

    def close_new_deal():
        new_deal_window.destroy()
        button_new_deal['state'] = 'normal'

    def user_input():
        symbol_label = Label(new_deal_window, text="Ticker")
        symbol_label.place(x=10, y=50)
        screener_label = Label(new_deal_window, text="Screener")
        screener_label.place(x=10, y=80)
        exchange_label = Label(new_deal_window, text="Exchange")
        exchange_label.place(x=10, y=110)
        number_label = Label(new_deal_window, text="Number")
        number_label.place(x=10, y=140)
        sum_label = Label(new_deal_window, text="Sum")
        sum_label.place(x=10, y=170)
        symbol_entry = Entry(new_deal_window)
        symbol_entry.place(x=100, y=50)
        screener_entry = Entry(new_deal_window)
        screener_entry.place(x=100, y=80)
        exchange_entry = Entry(new_deal_window)
        exchange_entry.place(x=100, y=110)
        number_entry = Entry(new_deal_window)
        number_entry.place(x=100, y=140)
        sum_entry = Entry(new_deal_window)
        sum_entry.place(x=100, y=170)
        return symbol_entry, screener_entry, exchange_entry, number_entry, sum_entry

    button_new_deal['state'] = ['disabled']
    new_deal_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    new_deal_window.geometry("400x500")
    new_deal_window.title("New deal")
    entry = user_input()
    button_add_deal = Button(new_deal_window, text="Add deal", command=add_new_deal())
    button_add_deal.pack()
    new_deal_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_new_deal)

# Create main window
main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry("1280x960")
main_window.title("Invest monitor")
icon = PhotoImage(file='clipart3605240.png')
main_window.iconphoto(True, icon)
# Create menubar
menubar = Menu(main_window)
main_window.config(menu=menubar)
program = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Program", menu=program)
program.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
program.add_command(label="About")
# Create notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(main_window)
investment_portfolio_tab = Frame(notebook)
plans_tab = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(investment_portfolio_tab, text="Investment portfolio")
notebook.add(plans_tab, text="Plans")
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
# Create button New Deal
button_new_deal = Button(investment_portfolio_tab, text="New deal", command=new_deal)
button_new_deal.pack()
# Initialize
main_window.mainloop()
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a new TopLevel window "new_deal_window" in the function "new_deal". In continue, i'm creating some labels and entry boxes (which are supposed to be filled with some value) in the function called "user_input", and then i would like to clear this values whit the button "button_add_deal".

In my opinion, i have some issues whit the type conversation, but i don't know where it is exactly.

Comment: So, when you click `add deal`, it should clear all the entry boxes?

Comment: @PCM Yes, it is.

Comment: Just a small suggestion: Avoid importing everything from a module. It may cause in some errors. Thanks.

Comment: Change `command=add_new_deal()` to `command=add_new_deal`.

Comment: @IshaanJog thanks for your advice, take a note!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the command bound to a Button or event executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-the-command-bound-to-a-button-or-event-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could clear each `Entry` alone . To do this :

```
entry_name.delete('0','end')
```

Or,you coud also do the following :

```
def clear(*args):
    for i in args :
        i.delete('0','end')
```

then you have to pass all your entries as `arguments` to this function .

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: My solution is for each entry use  'entry_name.delete('0','end')' for exemple : sum_entry.delete('0','end') and do the same process for all your entries .

Comment: I edit my answer  in order to minimise your code .